# Questions without a try

Tags: discussion, flags

How should I flag questions on `review` when they have a certain question in it but it's obvious that the person asking didn't google anything. Is `Should be closed` | `unclear what you're asking -> go to "how to ask"` appropriate?

Comment: If there is a duplicate question, you should flag it as duplicate and point to the other question. If not, I don't know.  But the last is highly doubtful when "it's obvious that the person [...] didn't google anything".